# Cosmos DB with AT commands by using SIM868e

Tags: http, azure-cosmosdb, at-command, arduino-esp32, sim800

I am using SIM868e to communicate with Azure cosmos Db for my application. i am trying to use http GET for container from my Azure cosmos db. But i am not able to do it. I am using AT commands. Below are the AT command lines and responses:

```
AT
OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"
OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,APN,"internet"
OK
AT+SAPBR=1,1
OK
AT+SAPBR=2,1
+SAPBR: 1,1,"100.83.233.231"
AT+HTTPINIT
OK
AT+HTTPSSL=1
OK
AT+HTTPPARA=CID,"1"
OK
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","https://wm-testdb.documents.azure.com/dbs/WM/colls"
OK
AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"
OK
AT+HTTPPARA="USERDATA","Authorization:type=master&ver=1.0&sig={primary read only key}\r\nx-ms-version:2018-12-31\r\nx-ms-date:Thu, 30 Jun 2022 13:05:09 GMT"
OK
AT+HTTPACTION=0
OK
+HTTPACTION: 0,401,425
AT+HTTPREAD
+HTTPREAD: 425
{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"The input authorization token can't serve the request. The wrong key is being used or the expected payload is not built as per the protocol. For more info: https://ak
```

I am using primary key "Read only Keys" in authorization and real time for "x-ms-date:"

HARDWARE:

I am using SIM868e module which is connected with Hardware Serial2 of ESP32-wroom-32U and i am using arduino's serial monitor to send AT command lines to sim868e from ESP32.

Comment: Not sure if you embedded your actual auth key in your example, but if you did, you should regenerate a key asap.

Comment: @DavidMakogon i have tried that as well still getting the same message.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. I'm not pointing out something wrong with what you posted (I haven't tried analyzing it in detail) - I'm saying you shared your security key, which means (if that is your real key), others reading your question can now access your Cosmos DB instance.

Comment: I have no familiarity with the command set for this hardware but if you're trying to communicate with Cosmos via REST, I would refer to the samples here on GitHub. Please be sure to follow these precisely. Somethings are case sensitive here. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cosmos-db-rest-samples